# UWP StorageFile.CopyAsync() Throwing Error: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile, storagefolder

I am trying to overwrite a file with a new version inside of an AppData sub-directory.

Current process is that the user has to select the File to overwrite, and the folder directory it sits in separately so that I can add them to the future access list. Later on the user can select from a collection of images, and it's at that point that it needs to copy and overwrite the destination file. The code I've tried to do this is as follows:

```
// lets try to copy file to wallpaper default location.
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
var faToken = localSettings.Values["WallpaperStorageFileFAToken"] as string;
var faTokenFolder = localSettings.Values["WallpaperStorageFolderFAToken"] as string;

var destinationFile = await LoadExistingFileSelection(faToken);
var destinationFolder = await LoadExistingFolderSelection(faTokenFolder);

StorageFile movedFile = null;
try
{
    movedFile = await imageFile.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, destinationFile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
catch (Exception genEx)
{
    //
}
```

The `Fa` tokens are taken after an `FileOpenPicker` is used by the User to get the `StorageFile` and a `FolderPicker` used to get the `StorageFolder` for the directory of the destination.

LoadExistingFolderSelection and LoadExistingFileSelection use the following bits of code to get the `StorageFiles` and `StorageFolder`

```
await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(faToken);
```

and

```
await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(faFolderToken);
```

The issue is that this line:

```
imageFile.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, destinationFile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Throws this error:

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

and that's it, literally nothing else, any thoughts would be great.

Comment: When I used your code to test it, it worked well. Can you show the complete code for us to reproduce it?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I may try to put it all into a git repo at some point today, but is there any chance this is a permissions issue, I mean I can copy files directly into the appdata folder I'm trying to overwrite the file in manually.

Comment: The app's localfolder directory can read and write, it won't exist permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes... Honestly this is one of those moments in you're development career where you just sit there and sigh, because it's just so dumb.

So I could happily retrieve the image I wanted to copy absolutely fine into a `StorageFile` object, with a path that contained 1 additional backslash that the Windows OS File Explorer wouldn't have batted an eye lid about.

No problem so far, great proceed to then run a copy operation against that, and suddenly you get the

> “Value does not fall within the expected range.”

exception, argue-ably one of the least helpful exceptions relating to a problem with a file path that I've seen.

So there you have it, backslashes, really carefully examine the Path property. Hindsight. Normally I would just remove that question because this answer isn't particularly any kind of great revelation. But I figure it can stay as a warning about the fearsome **backslash** and UWP's Storage API.